# undefined method `response' for nil:NilClass rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I created a test, and for some reason the should is run on a nil type.
I am using rails 4.2 and rspec-rails 3.1.0. I am not sure what I am doing wrong - this is the test, and the error is on the last `it { should respond_with 401 }` test

```
require 'rails_helper'

class Authentication
  include Authenticable
  def request
  end

  def response
  end
end

describe Authenticable do
  let(:authentication) { Authentication.new }

  describe "#current_user" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      request.headers["Authorization"] = @user.auth_token
      allow(authentication).to receive(:request).and_return(request)
    end
    it "returns the user from the authorization header" do
      expect(authentication.current_user.auth_token).to eql @user.auth_token
    end
  end

  describe "#authenticate_with_token" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      allow(authentication).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
      allow(response).to receive(:response_code).and_return(401)
      allow(response).to receive(:body).and_return({"errors" => "Not authenticated"}.to_json)
      allow(authentication).to receive(:response).and_return(response)
    end

    it "render a json error message" do
      expect(json_response[:errors]).to eql "Not authenticated"
    end

    it {  should respond_with 401 }
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like `response` in `allow(response)` is not set prior to being used in your before block. What is that variable/method name referring to?

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of that `authenticate_with_token` test, ur faking the request and the response, and the expecting the fake response, shouldn't you at least do a single request ?

Comment: I am not really sure, I am using a tutorial and the response was just there - I think it's an rspec thing - because I didn't define it.

Comment: Do you have infer_spec_type_from_file_location! turned on?

Comment: that's what the guy on apionrails tutorial is doing, don't ask me what's the point, I just know it works for him but not for me. The thing is he is using rails 4, and the old rspec syntax.

Comment: infer_spec_type_from_file_location! is turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it {  should respond_with 401 }` does not specify which object should repond with 401, that's why the error.

To fix it try:

```
expect(response).to respond_with 401
```

or 
use [subject](http://betterspecs.org/#subject):

```
subject{ response }
it {  should respond_with 401 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
subject { authentication }
```

you should put this line as below

```
let(:authentication) { Authentication.new }
subject { authentication }
describe '#current_user' do
```